# Android gradle :app:packageDebug FAILED: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bouncycastle

I'm new to Android and I can't get my first app to run. Whenever I try, it's throwing this error:

**`Android gradle :app:packageDebug FAILED: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.`**

I googled it and I found many questions there. As many said, this problem is probably due to the fact that I have multiple dependencies on BouncyCastle in my project. I tryed to remove the .gradle folder both in my project and in my local folder so I could download again the jars from the repository but nothing has changed. I also double checked that my JAVA_HOME is set and it's pointing to a 1.7 version. I tryed to gradle :app:clean and gradle :app:dependencies to see if I was missing something but still... I can't see any dependency from BouncyCastle... Can anybody help me?

Also, this problem occured without me changing any code... The app successfully worked yesterday and now is giving me this error... I don't get it. Thank you.

**EDIT**

**gradle.build**

**Top-level:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

**Module app:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.aurasphere.provaactionbar"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile project(':volley')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
}
```

**Module volley:**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion = '21.1.0'
}

apply from: 'rules.gradle'
```

rules.gradle for module volley:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Comment: You'll need to put your Gradle config file here. Any chance you're including a snapshot version of anything?

Comment: @chrylis I don't think I'm including any snapshot... Do you mean the build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes, both the top-level and for any modules you may have.

Comment: @chrylis I've added the gradle files. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem myself just by changing the JDK I was using from x32 to x64 and now is compiling correctly.